# wp_update_post "post_title" with html characters

Tags: wordpress

I need to set post_title like this:

```
wp_update_post(array('ID' => 1, 'post_title' => '<div id="123">Hello, world!</div>');
```

But title is converted to the following after the function is exucuted:

```
<div>Hello, world!</div>
```

Please advice how to set that title?

P.S. Version of Wordpress engine is the latest.

Comment: couldn't understand your issue mate.

Comment: If you execute wp_update_post() as mentioned above you will see <div>Hello, world!</div> in the title instead of <div id="123">Hello, world!</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the filter kses before update post args with the function :

kses_remove_filters();

example :

```
  // Update post
  $my_post = array(
      'ID'           => 1,
      'post_title'   => '<b>This</b> is the<br> test.',
  );

  remove_filter( 'title_save_pre', 'wp_filter_kses' ); // disable clean html 

  // Update the post into the database
  wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

documentation :
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/kses_remove_filters/